# LibGDX - Gradient rectangle using 2x2 texture (or similar way?)

Tags: opengl, libgdx

CMIIW: I heard libgdx's ShapeRenderer is slow and it is better to use Batch.

I tried using Pixmap to produce 2x2 texture and rely on the linear blending:

```
public void rect(Batch batch, float x, float y, float w, float h, float rot, Color c00, Color c01, Color c10, Color c11){
    Pixmap pm = new Pixmap(2, 2, Format.RGBA4444);
    pm.drawPixel(0, 0, Color.rgba8888(c00));
    pm.drawPixel(0, 1, Color.rgba8888(c01));
    pm.drawPixel(1, 0, Color.rgba8888(c10));
    pm.drawPixel(1, 1, Color.rgba8888(c11));

    Texture tx = new Texture(pm);
    tx.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

    batch.end();
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(new TextureRegion(tx), x, y, w/2f, h/2f, w, h, 1f, 1f, rot, true);
    batch.end();
    batch.begin();
    tx.dispose();
    pm.dispose();
}
```

And it produces this:
[image]

It is not the effect I would want.
If I could throw half pixel from each side of the texture then I think it would be good.

I thought in order to do that I have to change the TextureRegion to this:
    `new TextureRegion(tx, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1f, 1f)`

but this produces:
[image]

What is happening there?

Or is there better way to efficiently draw gradient rectangle?

EDIT:

Ouch! Thanks TenFour04 - I tried with 
`new TextureRegion(tx, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.75f, 0.75f)` but got this instead:
[image]

weird, I got exactly what I want with 

`new TextureRegion(tx, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.87f, 0.87f)`:
[image]

looks like some rounding problem? 0.126f would still give me that (seemingly) but 0.125f would give me something much closer to the very first image in the post.

@Pinkie Swirl: hmm right, I wanted a method to draw gradient rectangles because I don't want to make textures, but in the end I do.. actually I can avoid making those 2x2 textures on the fly.

@minos

Comment: Do you need to create it one the fly? Otherwise I would suggest that you create such an image in a paint program. And be careful with Pixmap, too. As it is quite expensive.

Comment: What is the exact  effect that you want to do ?

Comment: Set the texture region using (0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75).